# How do I create a new user in Lion from the Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, directory-utility

The older method of:

```
dscl . -create /Users/username
```

doesn't work because `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist` can't be found. From what I gather, OSX Lion doesn't use this method anymore.

How can I create a new user solely from the Terminal?

Comment: `dscl .` launches interactive mode for me. This should still work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They renamed the Directory Services daemon in Lion:

```
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist
```